# How to apply the SUMIFS function from Excel to a Pandas DataFrame with several conditions

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I would like to apply this Excel SUMIFS-function:

```
=SUMIFS(F:F;D:D;">="&I2;D:D;"<"&I3)
```

to a DataFrame in Python.

[This is the Excel spreadsheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5p3ID.png)

I have loaded the current dataset from Excel, which are the columns from A to F, into Python by the pd.read_csv() function and converted it to pandas DataFrame. I have managed to concatenate three DataFrames into one and added the columns "Type" and " CT nr." with strings for further processing.

```
S_Pore_TotalFines = pd.concat([SD_Pore_df, SE_Pore_df, SF_Pore_df]).reset_index(drop=True)

S_Pore_TotalFines["Volume"] = (S_Pore_TotalFines["Area"])*resolution

S_Pore_TotalFines



 out[]: 
Label   Area    Minor   Slice   Type    CT nr.  Volume
0   SR20220510_3D = 28.03.22 (5) Stade Fines 60s.t...   0.009921    0.095951    163 Stade Fines 3D  0.000447
1   SR20220510_3D = 28.03.22 (5) Stade Fines 60s.t...   0.022548    0.139376    164 Stade Fines 3D  0.001016
2   SR20220510_3D = 28.03.22 (5) Stade Fines 60s.t...   0.006313    0.071339    164 Stade Fines 3D  0.000284
3   SR20220510_3D = 28.03.22 (5) Stade Fines 60s.t...   0.028861    0.141311    165 Stade Fines 3D  0.001300
4   SR20220510_3D = 28.03.22 (5) Stade Fines 60s.t...   0.002706    0.048512    165 Stade Fines 3D  0.000122
... ... ... ... ... ... ... ...
986719  SR20220510_3F = 20.04.22 (2) Stade Fines 180s....   0.001804    0.033887    639 Stade Fines 3F  0.000081
986720  SR20220510_3F = 20.04.22 (2) Stade Fines 180s....   0.009019    0.083591    639 Stade Fines 3F  0.000406
986721  SR20220510_3F = 20.04.22 (2) Stade Fines 180s....   0.004510    0.049875    640 Stade Fines 3F  0.000203
986722  SR20220510_3F = 20.04.22 (2) Stade Fines 180s....   0.002706    0.048512    641 Stade Fines 3F  0.000122
986723  SR20220510_3F = 20.04.22 (2) Stade Fines 180s....   0.002706    0.048512    641 Stade Fines 3F  0.000122
986724 rows × 7 columns
```

The column "Pore Diameter" in the Excel spreadsheet consists of a range from 0-50 multiplied by a scalar. Like the type:

```
resrange = [i*resolution for i in range(50)]
```

Now I want to sum the values from "Volume" **if** the corresponding "Minor" value is within the range between the values in "Pore Diameter". The summed "Volume" values together with the "pore Diameter"-range should preferably be put in a new column in the existing DataFrame ("Pore Diameter" and "Sum Pore Volume") so I have a DataFrame equal to the excel spreadsheet.

I don't have that much experience with DataFrame so I don't know which commands to use to achieve this.

Comment: post your sample dataframe as code, not a picture

Comment: Its a lot of data, but I have now edited the post with the output. You mean like this?

Comment: just a sample is fine, and post it as code so we can put it in our IDE